# New created products are not coming in category pages or search pages

Tags: category-products, magento2.4.4

New created products are not coming in category pages or search pages .

Where should i debug to find why they are not comming in front-end.

Even direct product view they are showing in front-end.

Comment: Reindex the catalog will work.

Comment: @SohelRana i did same but in local they are showing fine not in cloud server they are  comming what could be issue ?

Comment: Check elasticsearch/opensearch config, check the magento log

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the cron job is running properly.

Also please run the below command

php bin/magento indexer: reindex

php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 0):

Check the Elastic search active or not using below command.

```
systemctl status elasticsearch.service
```

If active then run below commands

```
php bin/magento indexer: reset

php bin/magento indexer: reindex

php bin/magento c:f
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

- Check product settings in Admin. **Go to Catalog > Products**, open the product page and make sure the following fields are correctly configured:
  Enable Product = Yes.
- Stock Status: In Stock. Or if Out of Stock is the correct value, make sure that Display Out of Stock Products (**STORES > Settings > Configuration > CATALOG > Inventory > Stock Options > Display Out Of Stock Products**) is set to Yes (configured on global level).
- Categories: If you try to find the product on a category page, verify that the product is assigned to the category. To simplify troubleshooting, create a new category from the current page and assign a product to it.
- Visibility = Catalog, Search.
- In the Product in Websites section, make sure the product is assigned to the correct website.
- Switch the scope selector to the store view where you try to find your product on the storefront, and verify the same settings.
- Perform the full reindex, by running `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` from the console, and flush all cache in the Admin, under System > Tools > Cache Management, or from the console by running `php bin/magento cache:clean`.

If the above does not help, you can start further investigation by checking logs in the var/log directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. The product visibility is not set to "Catalog, Search" or "Catalog". To make sure that your products are visible in category pages and search results, you need to set the product visibility to "Catalog, Search" or "Catalog". You can do this by going to **Catalog > Products** and selecting the product that you want to change the visibility for. Then, click on the Advanced Inventory tab and change the Visibility dropdown to "Catalog, Search" or "Catalog".
2. The product is not assigned to any categories. In order for a product to be displayed in a category page, it needs to be assigned to that category. You can do this by going to **Catalog > Categories** and selecting the category that you want to add the product to. Then, click on the Products tab and click on the Add Product button. Select the product that you want to add to the category and click on the Add button.
3. The product index is not up to date. The product index is a database table that stores information about all of the products in your Magento store. If the product index is not up to date, then new products might not be displayed in category pages or search results. To update the product index,

   ```
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product
   ```
4. There is a problem with the product's data. If there is a problem with the product's data, such as a missing or incorrect product name, then the product might not be displayed in category pages or search results. To check for problems with the product's data, go to **Catalog > Products** and select the product that you want to check. Then, click on the General tab and review the product data. If you see any problems, correct them and then try to reindex the product.

Hope this will work.